# Bash for Windows - Replace all repeated tabs \t\t\t with a single tab \t for all files in a directory

Tags: windows, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Working with bash for Windows and trying to figure out if there is a simple way to replace all files in a directory with a single command.

I'm aware that

```
tr -s '\t' '\t' < inputFile > outputFile
```

should work, but is there a way to do this for all files in a directory if I have thousands I am looking to go through?

Comment: Do the files you want to process have a common file name extension that can be used?

Comment: Yup, *.txt in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use `sed` which can modify the files in place:

```
sed -r -i -e "s/\t+/\t/g" *.txt
```

You would need to change the `*.txt` to match the files you are interested in. The `-r` option enables the use of the `+` regular expression qualifier and the `-i` tells `sed` to modify the files in place instead of writing to standard output.

Comment: Thanks so much, this makes a lot of sense.  If I wanted to replace it with something else, say a space, I can easily just change the "/\t" portion to " " or whatever I may want, yes?

Comment: Yes, but remember that `-i` is going to do an in place replacement, so I suggest removing the `-i` option while you are testing various things.

Comment: Thanks. Final question, is there a way to target only multi-tabs? For example, \t+ targets 1-or-more.  So if I want to replace say, \t\t\t with anything, say '-', but leave just \t alone, is that possible?

Comment: Yes: `sed -e "s/\t\t\t/-/g" filename.txt`